# Dota not launching in Ubuntu 16

Tags: steam

It says that it is running but not showing even once.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried launching other games on Steam? I am not sure if it is a problem with Steam or Dota 2.

Comment: Start steam from the command line and try to run Dota 2, or start Dota 2 from the command line and see if there are any errors.

Comment: I have the same issue with 16.04. Preparing to launch pops up, disapears, doesnt load the game. Here's terminal output:

Answer (score 1):

This command solve the issue:

```
env LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1' /usr/bin/steam %U
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ALT-TAB to switch to the program. Also try switching viewports via the last icon on your dock (right above the mounted drives). If that does not work it may be a problem with your graphics and/or it does not run correctly on your computer.

Comment: From the screenshot, the amount of memory and % CPU used are way too small for Dota 2. It looks like Dota 2 is not fully launched.

Comment: there is no icon. you can see it @System Monitor and Steam - Libraries dota is running.